# My implementation of Swap<T> does not work?

Tags: c#, generics

So I write below quick code that should be working for refernce and struct types, but first one does not do anything useful at all and second is useless for `List<int>`. Can anyone point out bugs and design issues in below code?

```
public static void Swap<T>(T o1, T o2) where T : class, IComparable<T>
{
    if (o1.CompareTo(o2) != 0)
    {
        var temp = o1;
        o1 = o2;
        o2 = temp;
    }
}

public static void Swap<T>(ref T o1, ref T o2) where T : struct, IComparable<T>
{
    if (o1.CompareTo(o2) != 0)
    {
        var temp = o1;
        o1 = o2;
        o2 = temp;
    }
}
```

Why I'm trying to do so: I've read some SO questions about why there is no Swap in C#. Common claim is Swap is not useful and you should just use temp obj to do it. However, I am still not convinced. I am writing my code now and it uses a lot of swap. It looks really uncomfortable to have same code snippet spreaded everywhere. It is still annoying to have to have same lines in more than one method but much better for my projects.

**UPDATE:**

Based on all input, I realise how little I know about C# and have produced a correct and concise solution:

```
public static void Swap<T>(ref T o1, ref T o2)
{
        var temp = o1;
        o1 = o2;
        o2 = temp;
}
```

Two thoughts:

1. Is it useful to check if o1 and o2 are reference-equal in terms of performance? I guess it is not a very bad idea, but then should I use object.ReferenceEquals()? If yes, and if T is primitive type, does it invoke boxing?
2. Because ref keyword is used, we can't pass in elements of List. I write an extension method to swap List elements:

   ```
   public static void SwapElements<T>(this IList<T> list, int a, int b)
   {
       if (a < 0 || b < 0 || a >= list.Count || b >= list.Count || a > b)
           throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

       if (a == b) 
           return;

       var t = list[a]; list[a] = list[b]; list[b] = t;

       return list;
   }
   ```

Comment: This probably belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: `IEquatable<T>` would be a better interface to use. Some items can be compared for equality, but not ranked

Comment: your code does nothing. except changing some local variables' values.

Comment: `I am writing my code now and it uses a lot of swap` - post that code instead. I'm pretty sure there is a fundamental flaw in there.

Comment: Most real-world code doesn't use a lot of swaps. Sorting algorithms are a notable example of code that might use a lot of swaps, but those are rare because they're written and then reused. You typically don't write sorting algorithms yourself outside of an academic scenario.

Comment: Erm, who's complaining about swap in the first place?

Comment: Try to you your `Swap` with elements of `List<int>` :) ... Also consider adding unit tests to first one as @HighCore suggested indirectly.

Comment: @Paddy No it doesn’t, since it’s not correct. ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph - voting to reopen (also I've changed the question to match code... :) Sheen - feel free to update question after my edit if you feel it is necessary.

Comment: The second one should certainly swap two `List<int>`s... Swapping two elements within a list though would require a reference to the internal array, or else to identify them by index.

Comment: @TimS.: Directly swapping the contents of writable storage locations isn't terribly common, but there could have been benefits to having an `ISortableList<out T>` which inherited from a non-generic `IPermutable`, which included included a "swap elements by index" method.  It's not possible to perform a type-safe sorting operation on a covariant list if swapping items requires that they be read out and written back, but if the items don't have to leave the list, type safety can be maintained.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Ah, the question has changed somewhat from the original, now seems to fit.

Answer (score 1):

The first version, with reference types (the constraint `where T : class`), is clearly missing `ref` modifiers on the two parameters. Assigning new references to `o1` and `o2` changes absolutely nothing for the caller when the parameters are not passed "by ref".

So there is really no reason to have separate methods (by the way, two overloads are not allowed to have the same signatures, illegal C#!) for reference types and value types in this case.

Also, it is unclear why you do not wish to swap just because `CompareTo` gives `0`. It can still matter to swap the references; it could still be distinct instances.

You are probably confusing two unrelated concepts: (1) Reference types (`class`) and value types (`struct`). (2) ByRef parameters (`ref` or `out` keyword) and value parameters (neither `ref` nor `out` present).

---

***EDIT:*** You could test your understanding with this example:

```
class MyClass
{
  internal int Field;
}
struct MyStruct
{
  internal int Field; // NB! Many people consider mutable structs evil
}
static class Test
{
  static void Main()
  {
    var a = new MyClass();
    ChangeFieldOfMyClass_ByVal(a);
    Console.WriteLine(a.Field);

    var b = new MyStruct();
    ChangeFieldOfMyStruct_ByVal(b);
    Console.WriteLine(b.Field);

    var c = new MyClass();
    ChangeFieldOfMyClass_ByRef(ref c);
    Console.WriteLine(c.Field);

    var d = new MyStruct();
    ChangeFieldOfMyStruct_ByRef(ref d);
    Console.WriteLine(d.Field);


    var e = new MyClass();
    AssignToParameterMyClass_ByVal(e);
    Console.WriteLine(e.Field);

    var f = new MyStruct();
    AssignToParameterMyStruct_ByVal(f);
    Console.WriteLine(f.Field);

    var g = new MyClass();
    AssignToParameterMyClass_ByRef(ref g);
    Console.WriteLine(g.Field);

    var h = new MyStruct();
    AssignToParameterMyStruct_ByRef(ref h);
    Console.WriteLine(h.Field);
  }

  static void ChangeFieldOfMyClass_ByVal(MyClass p)
  {
    p.Field = 42;
  }
  static void ChangeFieldOfMyStruct_ByVal(MyStruct p)
  {
    p.Field = 42;
  }
  static void ChangeFieldOfMyClass_ByRef(ref MyClass p)
  {
    p.Field = 42;
  }
  static void ChangeFieldOfMyStruct_ByRef(ref MyStruct p)
  {
    p.Field = 42;
  }

  static void AssignToParameterMyClass_ByVal(MyClass p)
  {
    p = new MyClass { Field = 42, };
  }
  static void AssignToParameterMyStruct_ByVal(MyStruct p)
  {
    p = new MyStruct { Field = 42, };
  }
  static void AssignToParameterMyClass_ByRef(ref MyClass p)
  {
    p = new MyClass { Field = 42, };
  }
  static void AssignToParameterMyStruct_ByRef(ref MyStruct p)
  {
    p = new MyStruct { Field = 42, };
  }
}
```

The "value" of a class is a "reference" to a location of that instance of the class (object).

The "value" of a struct is all the struct instance fields taken togethed.

When something is passed "ByVal", the *value* is **copied** and handed to the method. For a class, that only involves copying the reference. We now have two distinct references to *the same object* on the heap. For a struct, copying the value means copying all the instance fields that this struct has.

When something is passed "ByRef", the method gets the very same value as the caller has. Nothing is copied. Same place in memory. For classes, there is *one* reference to the object. For structs, there is *one* place in memory where all the instance fields are kept.

(In the above, "class" could be a `class` type, `interface` type, `delegate` type or array type, and "struct" could be a `struct` type or `enum` type.)

C# also has **pointers**, in `unsafe` context, for example `MyStruct*` is the pointer type corresponding to `MyStruct`. Pointers (unlike "references" for `class` types) allow "arithmetics" like incrementing a pointer, or adding a value to a pointer. And you can cast pointers, for example from `MyStruct*` to `byte*`.

But pointers are rarely used. Avoid pointers like this: Use arrays (`MyStruct[]`) or generic collection types (e.g. `List<MyStruct>`) instead. If you want to re-interprete the data of say a `MyStruct` value into a list of four `byte` values (why?), make a method that does just this.

Comment: Thanks. It makes things clear. One more question, do I need to check if two refs are pointing to same object instance before swapping, so to save CPU cycles?

Comment: When T is reference type, void Swap<T>(T o1, T o2) is like void Swap<T>(T* o1, T* o2) in C++, and void Swap<T>(ref T o1, ref T o2) is like void Swap<T>(T*& o1, T*& o2) in C++.

When T is value type, void Swap<T>(T o1, T o2) is like void Swap<T>(T o1, T o2) in C++, and void Swap<T>(ref T o1, ref T o2) is like void Swap<T>(T& o1, T& o2) in C++.

Am I right?

Comment: @Sheen No, you should not check if they are the same before swapping. Not sure I know enough C++ to answer the last part. Instead I added an example in my answer above that covers all cases, plus some more explanations.